# How to load a page in specific div using angular7

Tags: angular, angular-material, sidenav

In my project, I have left side menu (like a side nav) that is developed using mat-tree and right side that show the contents when we select or click menu on left side.
Here, the highlighted with yellow is built using mat-tree [sideNav and contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8LmR.png) 
If we select any option from left side, say for example if I select "checkbox" as in given link [Content on selection of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jg6Q4.png) then the right side should load content without refresh and retain the left side nav.
Sample link for reference, https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview

Note: I already have a  in my app.component.html. This left nav and right side content is developed in diff component.html.
So, I will need a another  in a different component apart from app.component.html.
I tried having  in the component. When I navigate it's routing to a new page. What I want is to show in same page on right side.

Comment: So you need to render components in another component without routing change based on the selection in the sidenav?

Comment: On selecting it from mat-tree, it would hit the URL, the URL will have a tableau data. Need to show that URL content on the right side. - @Robertgarcia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the routing: https://angular.io/guide/router

In your root component's template (app.component.html), you can have the following structure:

```
<app-with-mat-tree></app-with-mat-tree>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Hi @NikNik
Thanks. But there is a problem I'm facing. I already have a <router-outlet> in app.component.html. And I need a one more <router-outlet> in another template, i.e in another component.html.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load any component in a particular section of a page you need to use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tag

I have created a simple demo for your understanding: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mof1tg

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Why repeating the same answer? Consider upvoting the existing one

Comment: The main reason was to provide a working solution as per his need and not just providing a generic answer